# Interperet english date string to use with date_format

Tags: php, smarty

In smarty, I have a date string formatted like this: DD/MM/YYYY

When I try to use `date_format` it gets the date wrong.

How can I make it understand what the initial string is formatted like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of [`date_format`](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.date.format.tpl) Smarty variable modifier explains what it expects for the value to be formatted:

> This formats a date and time into the given [`strftime()`](http://php.net/strftime) format. Dates can be passed to Smarty as [unix timestamps](http://php.net/function.time), [DateTime objects](http://php.net/class.DateTime), mysql timestamps or any string made up of month day year, parsable by php's [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime).

The date format you are using (`DD/MM/YYYY`) is [not recognized](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) by `strtotime()` and there is a good reason for it: for more that one third of the days of the year, this format cannot be told apart from `MM/DD/YYYY`. The PHP developers had to choose which of these two formats to recognize and they have chosen `MM/DD/YYYY` (probably because it has higher coverage).

A possible solution to your problem is to use the [`replace`](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.replace.tpl) modifier first, to change `/` to `-` or `.`. Both `DD-MM-YYYY` and `DD.MM.YYYY` formats are valid and recognized by `strtotime()` and they do not clash with other formats.

If your current code looks like:

```
{$date|date_format:'%e %B %Y'}
```

change it to:

```
{$date|replace:'/':'.'|date_format:'%e %B %Y'}
```